# Add a value in a javascript array as a last element- Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Below is my JSON body.

```
{"key":"OTH","value":{"Name":"Other Countries"}}
```

I need to add this 'Other Countries' value as a last value in below array 'countryMap'

```
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();    
            var countryMap = [];
            for(var key in result){                    
                countryMap.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
            }                
            component.set("v.countryList", countryMap);
        }
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? A quick lookup of documentation for array functions in Javascript suggests that `push()` is the function you're looking for.

Comment: In array 'CountryMap', i'm getting below values in dropdown;

Austria,
Canada,
France,
Germany,
Other Countries,
United States


Requirement : I have to add 'Other Countries' as the last value always.

Expected Output:

Austria,
Canada,
France,
Germany,
United States,
Other Countries

I've already tried everything but it didn;t work.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find and move the entry to the end yourself. Here's a simple example:

```
const countryMap = Object.entries(result) // converts Object to Array of [key, value] pairs
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value })) // converts Array of [key, value] to Array of { key, value } objects
const other = countryMap.splice(countryMap.findIndex(value => value.key === 'OTH'), 1); // Find and remove OTH entry
countryMap.push(other)
```

There are plenty of other possible ways to write this as well, but it should be sufficient for your purposes.

Your JSON isn't very explanatory, so I hope I guessed correctly. If not, further changes may be needed to this code.